# Planning a local conference: looking serious academic partners

Tags: conference

The computer science department of my university plans to organize a scientific international conference.

In order to increase the credit of the conference, I mean in order to make it more attractable to worldwide scientist we would like to affiliate the conference with a well known and serious organization such IEEE or ACM or Elsevier. That could make the conference more confident for the university partners. We just need the conference articles to be reference by a serious and international journal.

After contacting both IEEE, ACM and Elsevier, I got the information, about ACM requirements that «Benefits will accrue to the technical meeting because of the cooperation of ACM. Benefits will accrue to ACM because of its cooperation.» At the university, we don't agree that all the benefits of the conference will go to ACM as we also need the benefits of the conference locally.

Is there anyone or any university who has been in the shoes of my university?
Do you have any information, advice to give us? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about the ACM "benefits" and I wonder if you have misunderstood what they are saying.  It looks to me like it's just the obvious statement that the conference is good for both parties.  It's not like "benefits" only go to one party or the other.  Are you interpreting "benefits" as "money"?  That's not how I read it.

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed. The [guidelines](https://www.acm.org/special-interest-groups/volunteer-resources/conference-planning/1-3) actually also explicitly state that "Cooperation specifically excludes financial participation, responsibility, or liability on the part of ACM."